# Azure Devops - Widget to control pipeline builds for specific port

Tags: azure-devops, widget, azure-dashboard

Is there any widget similar to this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#build-history-widget where i would be able to filter all builds for a specific Port on that pipeline, without referencing the branch?

In our company we have multiple teams and each one has around 5 specific ports that can be selected on the azure build pipelines for testing purposes.
This type of widget is very good for the development teams , because they have big projects with a single branch for weeks or months at a time, that are deployed to their specific ports, and they can control it using the widget easily, by selecting that projet branch and it doesn't change for that time frame.

However on my team, not development, we have small projects, and don't always deploy them to a port for testing, and even when we do, it's something that lasts a couple of days, so this widget is not that good for our daily work.
I wanted to know if there is any similiar widget where i can specifiy "Pipeline X" and then there would be an option for other "filters" and one of them would be the "Deployment Port" where i could select "Alright one my teams ports is 2635, i want all the builds of this pipeline where that port was selected".

I have been searching for something like this without success soo this post is my last option to see if something like this exists, I tried to use the widgets that i could find out of the box for Azure Devops for my own purposes, and they don't really align, soo i wanted to find any type of widget that might align with my needs (if it exists ofc).

Thanks for any input in advance!